# Select all fields with group by clause in Ms. Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table which contain CHECKTIME, USERID, and CHECKTYPE. This CHECKTIME type is datetime. I want to get these data without duplicate CHECKTIME date. For example my data is like this:

```
USERID | CHECKTIME           | CHECKTYPE
1      | 2016-05-01 06:58:00 | I
1      | 2016-05-01 06:59:00 | I
1      | 2016-05-02 06:58:00 | I
1      | 2016-05-02 06:58:10 | I
1      | 2016-05-02 06:59:00 | I
```

Does anyone know how to remove that duplicate date? So, from above data, I can get result like this:

```
USERID | CHECKTIME           | CHECKTYPE
1      | 2016-05-01 06:58:00 | I
1      | 2016-05-02 06:58:00 | I
```

I already tried use distinct, but it doesn't works, because I have different time for each CHECKTIME. And I already use GROUP BY clause, but it can only give me result just 1 field.

My query right now is like this:

```
SELECT USERID, CHECKTYPE, CHECKTIME, DAY(CHECKTIME)
FROM CHECKINOUT
WHERE USERID = 259 
AND MONTH(CHECKTIME)='5' 
AND YEAR(CHECKTIME)='2016'
AND CHECKTYPE = 'I' 
GROUP BY DAY(CHECKTIME)
ORDER BY DAY(CHECKTIME) ASC
```

and it cames with error about aggregate function.

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicates from your table - or just so they view as unique records in a query?

Comment: Not removing it, but displaying it without duplicate row. It's like using group by, but doesn't know why my group by clause didn't work in access

Comment: Okay - updated SQL below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the time?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
USERID, Format([CHECKTIME],"yyyy/mm/dd") AS CHECKDATE, CHECKTYPE
FROM CHECKINOUT;
```

Results in two records without the time

```
USERID | CHECKTIME  | CHECKTYPE
1      | 2016-05-01 | I
1      | 2016-05-02 | I
```

Or are you looking for the first time for each unique day? This will do it

> EDIT: ADDED ORDER BY DATE CLAUSE

```
SELECT DISTINCT USERID, CHECKTYPE, 
    Format([CHECKTIME],"yyyy/mm/dd") AS CHECKDATE, 
    Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) AS FirstCheckTime
FROM CHECKINOUT
WHERE (Month([CheckTime])=5) AND (Year([CheckTime])=2016)
GROUP BY USERID, CHECKTYPE, Format([CHECKTIME],"yyyy/mm/dd")
HAVING ((USERID=1) AND (CHECKTYPE="I"))
ORDER BY Format([CHECKTIME],"yyyy/mm/dd");
```

Looks like this:

```
USERID  CHECKTYPE   CHECKDATE   FirstCheckTime
1          I      2016/05/01    2016-05-01 06:58:00
1          I      2016/05/02    2016-05-02 06:58:00
```

Comment: Indeed, I need first time checkin for each day. Still need the time, not only the date. It's like MIN clause, thats why I have ORDER BY clause

Comment: Updated alternative SQL clause for you

Comment: It result no data with your 2nd clause.. --edit, sorry, I have just change userid, and it works smoothly... thank you so much..

Comment: I used the data set you provided at the top. Change the USERID, CHECKTYPE, MONTH AND YEAR to match your data. Maybe you need userid =259?

Comment: Excellent - probably handier to add parameters - but it's a good test